# How to show full text when zoom in & truncate it when zoom out

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am creating a tree chart with d3.js, it works fine... but I want text to react to zooming, Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qko5dq64/5/).

Please look at first node... it has lots of characters (in my case max will be 255)

When zoomed in or out, my text remains same, but I want to see all on zoom in.

```js
var json = {
  "name": "Maude Charlotte Licia  Fernandez Maude Charlotte Licia  Fernandez Maude Charlotte Licia  Fernandez Maude Charlotte Licia  FernandezMaude Charlotte Licia  Fernandez Maude Charlotte Licia  Fernandez Maude Charlotte Licia  Fernandez Maude asdlkhkjh asd asdsd",
  "id": "06ada7cd-3078-54bc-bb87-72e9d6f38abf",
  "_parents": [{
    "name": "Janie Clayton Norton",
    "id": "a39bfa73-6617-5e8e-9470-d26b68787e52",
    "_parents": [{
      "name": "Pearl Cannon",
      "id": "fc956046-a5c3-502f-b853-d669804d428f",
      "_parents": [{
        "name": "Augusta Miller",
        "id": "fa5b0c07-9000-5475-a90e-b76af7693a57"
      }, {
        "name": "Clayton Welch",
        "id": "3194517d-1151-502e-a3b6-d1ae8234c647"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Nell Morton",
      "id": "06c7b0cb-cd21-53be-81bd-9b088af96904",
      "_parents": [{
        "name": "Lelia Alexa Hernandez",
        "id": "667d2bb6-c26e-5881-9bdc-7ac9805f96c2"
      }, {
        "name": "Randy Welch",
        "id": "104039bb-d353-54a9-a4f2-09fda08b58bb"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Helen Donald Alvarado",
    "id": "522266d2-f01a-5ec0-9977-622e4cb054c0",
    "_parents": [{
      "name": "Gussie Glover",
      "id": "da430aa2-f438-51ed-ae47-2d9f76f8d831",
      "_parents": [{
        "name": "Mina Freeman",
        "id": "d384197e-2e1e-5fb2-987b-d90a5cdc3c15"
      }, {
        "name": "Charlotte Ahelandro Martin",
        "id": "ea01728f-e542-53a6-acd0-6f43805c31a3"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Jesus Christ Pierce",
      "id": "bfd1612c-b90d-5975-824c-49ecf62b3d5f",
      "_parents": [{
        "name": "Donald Freeman Cox",
        "id": "4f910be4-b827-50be-b783-6ba3249f6ebc"
      }, {
        "name": "Alex Fernandez Gonzales",
        "id": "efb2396d-478a-5cbc-b168-52e028452f3b"
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

var boxWidth = 250,
  boxHeight = 100;

// Setup zoom and pan
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([.1, 1])
  .on('zoom', function() {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ") scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  })
  // Offset so that first pan and zoom does not jump back to the origin
  .translate([600, 600]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr('width', 1000)
  .attr('height', 500)
  .call(zoom)
  .append('g')
  // Left padding of tree so that the whole root node is on the screen.
  // TODO: find a better way
  .attr("transform", "translate(150,200)");

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  // Using nodeSize we are able to control
  // the separation between nodes. If we used
  // the size parameter instead then d3 would
  // calculate the separation dynamically to fill
  // the available space.
  .nodeSize([100, 200])
  // By default, cousins are drawn further apart than siblings.
  // By returning the same value in all cases, we draw cousins
  // the same distance apart as siblings.
  .separation(function() {
    return .9;
  })
  // Tell d3 what the child nodes are. Remember, we're drawing
  // a tree so the ancestors are child nodes.
  .children(function(person) {
    return person._parents;
  });

var nodes = tree.nodes(json),
  links = tree.links(nodes);

// Style links (edges)
svg.selectAll("path.link")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", elbow);

// Style nodes    
var node = svg.selectAll("g.person")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "person")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
  });

// Draw the rectangle person boxes
node.append("rect")
  .attr({
    x: -(boxWidth / 2),
    y: -(boxHeight / 2),
    width: boxWidth,
    height: boxHeight
  });

// Draw the person's name and position it inside the box
node.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .attr('class', 'name')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

// Text wrap on all nodes using d3plus. By default there is not any left or
// right padding. To add padding we would need to draw another rectangle,
// inside of the rectangle with the border, that represents the area we would
// like the text to be contained in.
d3.selectAll("text").each(function(d, i) {
  d3plus.textwrap()
    .container(d3.select(this))
    .valign("middle")
    .draw();
});


/**
 * Custom path function that creates straight connecting lines.
 */
function elbow(d) {
  return "M" + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x + "H" + (d.source.y + (d.target.y - d.source.y) / 2) + "V" + d.target.x + "H" + d.target.y;
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
svg {
  margin-top: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.person rect {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
.person {
  font: 14px sans-serif;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3plus/1.8.0/d3plus.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: still not clear what you want to achieve :(

Comment: @pritishvaidya What exactly is confusing you :)

Comment: you want the text to -not- truncate when you zoom in? because with d3 the apparent font size changes when zooming, are you expecting the text to come outside the box?

Comment: what do you want to do while zoom in and zoom out,please elaborate more

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 I want text to slowly start truncating less and less when zoom in but when all of the text is shown in rect then it may increase in size, if that makes sense ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d76z9vpm/6/) is an attempt to address the performance issues that you have with very large tree charts. A delay is set with `setTimeout` in the zoom event handler to allow zooming at "full speed", without text resizing. Once the zooming stops for a short time, the text is rearranged according to the new scaling:

```
var scaleValue = 1;
var refreshTimeout;
var refreshDelay = 0;

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([.1, 1.5])
    .on('zoom', function () {
        svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ") scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        scaleValue = d3.event.scale;
        if (refreshTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(refreshTimeout);
        }
        refreshTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            wrapText();
        }, refreshDelay);
    })
```

The delay (in milliseconds) depends on the number of nodes in the tree. You can experiment with the mathematical expression to find the best parameters for the wide range of node counts that you expect in your tree.

```
// Calculate the refresh delay
refreshDelay = Math.pow(node.size(), 0.5) * 2.0;
```

You can also set the parameters in `calcFontSize` to fit your needs:

```
// Calculate the font size for the current scaling
var calcFontSize = function () {
    return Math.min(24, 10 * Math.pow(scaleValue, -0.25))
}
```

The initialization of the nodes has been slightly modified:

```
node.append("rect")
    .attr({
        x: 0,
        y: -(boxHeight / 2),
        width: boxWidth,
        height: boxHeight
    });

node.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")
    .attr('class', 'name')
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    });
```

And the text is processed in `wrapText`:

```
// Adjust the font size to the zoom level and wrap the text in the container
var wrapText = function () {
    d3.selectAll("text").each(function (d, i) {
        var $text = d3.select(this);
        if (!$text.attr("data-original-text")) {
            // Save original text in custom attribute
            $text.attr("data-original-text", $text.text());
        }
        var content = $text.attr("data-original-text");
        var tokens = content.split(/(\s)/g);
        var strCurrent = "";
        var strToken = "";
        var box;
        var lineHeight;
        var padding = 4;
        $text.text("").attr("font-size", calcFontSize());
        var $tspan = $text.append("tspan").attr("x", padding).attr("dy", 0);
        while (tokens.length > 0) {
            strToken = tokens.shift();
            $tspan.text((strCurrent + strToken).trim());
            box = $text.node().getBBox();
            if (!lineHeight) {
                lineHeight = box.height;
            }
            if (box.width > boxWidth - 2 * padding) {
                $tspan.text(strCurrent.trim());
                if (box.height + lineHeight < boxHeight) {
                    strCurrent = strToken;
                    $tspan = $text.append("tspan").attr("x", padding).attr("dy", lineHeight).text(strCurrent.trim());
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                strCurrent += strToken;
            }
        }
        $text.attr("y", -(box.height - lineHeight) / 2);
    });
}
```

Comment: I modified the code to improve performance and reduced the refresh delay.

Answer (score 16):

I made a sample of your requirement in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qko5dq64/52/)

It may need some more tweaking to position the text vertical middle; but this can be the base for you to work on. Calculations are done in the function `wrap()` and call on page load and zooming.

```
function wrap() {
  var texts = d3.selectAll("text"),
    lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
    padding = 2, // px
    fSize = scale > 1 ? fontSize / scale : fontSize,
    // find how many lines can be included
    lines = Math.floor((boxHeight - (2 * padding)) / (lineHeight * fSize)) || 1;
  texts.each(function(d, i) {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = d.name.split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("dy", "-0.5em").style("font-size", fSize + "px");
    while ((word = words.pop())) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      // check if the added word can fit in the box
      if ((tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() + (2 * padding)) > boxWidth) {
        // remove current word from line
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        lineNumber++;
        // check if a new line can be placed
        if (lineNumber > lines) {
          // left align text of last line
          tspan.attr("x", (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() - boxWidth) / 2 + padding);
          --lineNumber;
          break;
        }
        // create new line
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word]; // place the current word in new line
        tspan = text.append("tspan")
          .style("font-size", fSize + "px")
          .attr("dy", "1em")
          .text(word);
      }
      // left align text
      tspan.attr("x", (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() - boxWidth) / 2 + padding);
    }
    // align vertically inside the box
    text.attr("text-anchor", "middle").attr("y", padding - (lineHeight * fSize * lineNumber) / 2);
  });
}
```

Also note that I've added the style `dominant-baseline: hanging;` to `.person` class

Comment: Thank you for the answer... it looks like what I need, but it made it very buggy and hard to work with it :(

Comment: What are the main bugs you notice using the wrap function? Maybe I could help in fixing those.

Comment: One of main problem I am facing is that screen is taking too long to respond to zooming now as compared to before. Reason is obvious for it being slow but am afraid if it will full fill my requirements :(

Comment: @Mathematics I've updated the code to improve performance and fix last line fitting issue. If your application needs much more performance, I strongly suggest to use canvas instead of SVG for rendering the tree. See [this example performance comparison](http://codepen.io/chris-creditdesign/pen/BIADJ/) of drawing same dataset with canvas and SVG. Canvas is about 400-600% faster than SVG!

Comment: I can see the performance has improved and thank you for that, however I never worked with canvas, Is changing this code into canvas something easy to do or is there a big learning curve ? thank you again

Comment: There are plugins available to use canvas instead of SVG for d3, and it seems d3 v4 natively supports canvas. Here are some links. [Learnings from a D3.js addict on starting with Canvas](http://www.visualcinnamon.com/2015/11/learnings-from-a-d3-js-addict-on-starting-with-canvas.html), [Using Canvas and D3](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/using-canvas-and-d3), [d3js and canvas](https://bocoup.com/weblog/d3js-and-canvas), [D3 Without SVG](http://vallandingham.me/d3_without_svg.html) and [SO Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js%20canvas). You can google for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Text wrapping can be process intensive if we have a lot of text. To address those issues, present in [my first answer](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanchaer/b3xr4rLL/), this [new version](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanchaer/k3nm5as0/) has improved performance, thanks to pre-rendering.

This script creates an element outside of the `DOM`, and stores all nodes and edges into it. Then it checks which elements would be visible, removing them from the `DOM`, and adding them back when appropriate.

I'm making use of `jQuery` for `data()`, and for selecting elements. In my example on the fiddle, there are 120 nodes. But it should work similarly for much more, as the only nodes rendered are the ones on screen.

I changed the zoom behaviour, so that the zoom is centered on the mouse cursor, and was surprised to see that the pan / zoom works on iOS as well.

[See it in action.](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanchaer/k3nm5as0/)

**UPDATE**

I applied the timeout (ConnorsFan's solution), as it makes a big difference. In addition, I added a minimum scale for which text should be re-wrapped.

```
$(function() {

    var viewport_width = $(window).width(),
        viewport_height = $(window).height(),
        node_width = 120,
        node_height = 60,
        separation_width = 100,
        separation_height = 55,
        node_separation = 0.78,
        font_size = 20,
        refresh_delay = 200,
        refresh_timeout,

        zoom_extent = [0.5, 1.15],

        // Element outside DOM, to calculate pre-render
        buffer = $("<div>");

    // Parse "transform" attribute
    function parse_transform(input_string) {
        var transformations = {},
            matches, seek;
        for (matches in input_string = input_string.match(/(\w+)\(([^,)]+),?([^)]+)?\)/gi)) {
            seek = input_string[matches].match(/[\w.\-]+/g), transformations[seek.shift()] = seek;
        }
        return transformations;
    }

    // Adapted from ConnorsFan's answer
    function get_font_size(scale) {
        fs = ~~Math.min(font_size, 15 * Math.pow(scale, -0.25));
        fs = ~~(((font_size / scale) + fs) / 2)
        return [fs, fs]
    }

    // Use d3plus to wrap the text
    function wrap_text(scale) {
        if (scale > 0.75) {
            $("svg > g > g").each(function(a, b) {
                f = $(b);
                $("text", f)
                    .text(f.data("text"));
            });
            d3.selectAll("text").each(function(a, b) {
                d3_el = d3.select(this);

                d3plus.textwrap()
                    .container(d3_el)
                    .align("center")
                    .valign("middle")
                    .width(node_width)
                    .height(node_height)
                    .valign("middle")
                    .resize(!0)
                    .size(get_font_size(scale))
                    .draw();
            });
        }
    }

    // Handle pre-render (remove elements that leave viewport, add them back when appropriate) 
    function pre_render() {
        buffer.children("*")
            .each(function(i, el) {
                d3.transform(d3.select(el).attr("transform"));
                var el_path = $(el)[0],
                    svg_wrapper = $("svg"),
                    t = parse_transform($("svg > g")[0].getAttribute("transform")),

                    element_data = $(el_path).data("coords"),

                    element_min_x = ~~element_data.min_x,
                    element_max_x = ~~element_data.max_x,
                    element_min_y = ~~element_data.min_y,
                    element_max_y = ~~element_data.max_y,

                    svg_wrapper_width = svg_wrapper.width(),
                    svg_wrapper_height = svg_wrapper.height(),

                    s = parseFloat(t.scale),
                    x = ~~t.translate[0],
                    y = ~~t.translate[1];

                if (element_min_x * s + x <= svg_wrapper_width &&
                    element_min_y * s + y <= svg_wrapper_height &&
                    0 <= element_max_x * s + x &&
                    0 <= element_max_y * s + y) {

                    if (0 == $("#" + $(el).prop("id")).length) {

                        if (("n" == $(el).prop("id").charAt(0))) {
                            // insert nodes above edges
                            $(el).clone(1).appendTo($("svg > g"));
                            wrap_text(scale = t.scale);
                        } else {
                            // insert edges
                            $(el).clone(1).prependTo($("svg > g"));
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                    id = $(el).prop("id");
                    $("#" + id).remove();
                }
            });
    }
    d3.scale.category20();
    var link = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", viewport_width)
        .attr("height", viewport_height)
        .attr("pointer-events", "all")
        .append("svg:g")
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent(zoom_extent)),
        layout_tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .nodeSize([separation_height * 2, separation_width * 2])
        .separation(function() {
            return node_separation;
        })
        .children(function(a) {
            return a._parents;
        }),
        nodes = layout_tree.nodes(json),
        edges = layout_tree.links(nodes);

    // Style links (edges)
    link.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(edges)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(a) {
            return "M" + a.source.y + "," + a.source.x + "H" + ~~(a.source.y + (a.target.y - a.source.y) / 2) + "V" + a.target.x + "H" + a.target.y;
        });

    // Style nodes
    var node = link.selectAll("g.person")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(a) {
            return "translate(" + a.y + "," + a.x + ")";
        })
        .attr("class", "person");

    // Draw the rectangle person boxes
    node.append("rect")
        .attr({
            x: -(node_width / 2),
            y: -(node_height / 2),
            width: node_width,
            height: node_height
        });

    // Draw the person's name and position it inside the box
    node_text = node.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .text(function(a) {
            return a.name;
        });

    // Text wrap on all nodes using d3plus. By default there is not any left or
    // right padding. To add padding we would need to draw another rectangle,
    // inside of the rectangle with the border, that represents the area we would
    // like the text to be contained in.
    d3.selectAll("text")
        .each(function(a, b) {
            d3plus.textwrap()
                .container(d3.select(this))
                .valign("middle")
                .resize(!0)
                .size(get_font_size(1))
                .draw();
        });

    // START Create off-screen render

    // Append node edges to memory, to allow pre-rendering
    $("svg > g > path")
        .each(function(a, b) {
            el = $(b)[0];
            if (d = $(el)
                .attr("d")) {
                // Parse d parameter from rect, in the format found in the d3 tree dom: M0,0H0V0V0
                for (var g = d.match(/([MLQTCSAZVH])([^MLQTCSAZVH]*)/gi), c = g.length, h, k, f, l, m = [], e = [], n = 0; n < c; n++) {
                    command = g[n], void 0 !== command && ("M" == command.charAt(0) ? (coords = command.substring(1, command.length), m.push(~~coords.split(",")[0]), e.push(~~coords.split(",")[1])) : "V" == command.charAt(0) ? e.push(~~command.substring(1, command.length)) : "H" == command.charAt(0) && m.push(~~command.substring(1, command.length)));
                }
                0 < m.length && (h = Math.min.apply(this, m), f = Math.max.apply(this, m));
                0 < e.length && (k = Math.min.apply(this, e), l = Math.max.apply(this, e));
                $(el).data("position", a);
                $(el).prop("id", "e" + a);
                $(el).data("coords", {
                    min_x: h,
                    min_y: k,
                    max_x: f,
                    max_y: l
                });
                // Store element coords in memory
                hidden_element = $(el).clone(1);
                buffer.append(hidden_element);
            }
        });

    // Append node elements to memory
    $("svg > g > g").each(function(a, b) {
        el = $("rect", b);
        transform = b.getAttribute("transform");
        null !== transform && void 0 !== transform ? (t = parse_transform(transform), tx = ~~t.translate[0], ty = ~~t.translate[1]) : ty = tx = 0;
        // Calculate element area
        el_min_x = ~~el.attr("x");
        el_min_y = ~~el.attr("y");
        el_max_x = ~~el.attr("x") + ~~el.attr("width");
        el_max_y = ~~el.attr("y") + ~~el.attr("height");
        $(b).data("position", a);
        $(b).prop("id", "n" + a);
        $(b).data("coords", {
            min_x: el_min_x + tx,
            min_y: el_min_y + ty,
            max_x: el_max_x + tx,
            max_y: el_max_y + ty
        });
        text_el = $("text", $(b));
        0 < text_el.length && $(b).data("text", d3.select(text_el[0])[0][0].__data__.name);

        // Store element coords in memory
        hidden_element = $(b).clone(1);
        // store node in memory
        buffer.append(hidden_element);
    });

    // END Create off-screen render

    d3_svg = d3.select("svg");
    svg_group = d3.select("svg > g");

    // Setup zoom and pan
    zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .on("zoom", function() {
            previous_transform = $("svg > g")[0].getAttribute("transform");
            svg_group.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.scale + "px");
            svg_group.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
            pre_render();

            if (previous_transform !== null) {
                previous_transform = parse_transform(previous_transform);
                if (previous_transform.scale != d3.event.scale) {

                    // ConnorsFan's solution
                    if (refresh_timeout) {
                        clearTimeout(refresh_timeout);
                    }
                    scale = d3.event.scale;
                    refresh_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        wrap_text(scale = scale);
                    }, refresh_delay, scale);

                }
            }
        });
    // Apply initial zoom / pan
    d3_svg.call(zoom);
});
```

Comment: thank you for your effort, but it looks too slow to use :*(, +1 anyway... but if you could improve the performance as I will upto 50 - 10,000 nodes in future...

Comment: @Mathematics I see! Any way I could get my hands on some sample data with a couple of thousands of nodes? Would be a good way for me to see if I can work it out. You could perhaps put it on pastebin.com? Thanks!

Comment: @Mathematics don't worry with providing the data! I managed to create a sample dataset and see the problems! I'll let you know if I figure out a way to improve the performance.